# Call Array Into New Array To Perform Filter In Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, dictionary, filter

I have an array that I'm using map method to filter results from that array and output new array which i can then call into a print function. The problem is, I can't get the new array to output filtered items and it repeats the values from the original array multiple times into console. I also can't call the new array into the print function.

My goal is to use the first array to pull related stores, then the second array will filterable using angular filter direct in the view. Once that filter is applied, I want to be able to call the filtered data of the second array to print.

Any ideas or direction greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
printStoreList = function () {
    var storeDetail = function (store) {
        var result;

        {
            result = [];
            result.push(store.StoreName);
            result.push(store.Address);
            result.push(store.Phone);
            result.push(store.Zip);
            result.push(store.Is24Hour);
        }

        result.map(function(storeList){
            console.log(result); //This outputs duplicates of each array from above
            return {
                storeZip: storeList.Zip,
                storeName: storeList.StoreName,
                storeAddress: storeList.Address,
                storePhone: storeList.Phone
            };
        });

        return result;//This returns original array
    };
```

On second array I want to be able to use something similar to the following code to pass filtered data to print function:

```
if ((store.StoreName.indexOf($scope.query) >=0) || $scope.query === undefined ){(Second_Array)};
```

I can perform the filter on the first array and all works as planned, but I don't want to alter first array. I want to leave output of that array with everything returned, create second array from that array and filter that to return values to print function.

Comment: Maybe see if this will help https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter?

Comment: `map()` does not modify original array...it returns a new array

Comment: When map() returns the new array, can I use the filter if statement to filter that array and then output using return storeList;  ?

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log statement is printing the results array each time the map function iterates. 
I am not sure what is that you want to accomplish.

```
console.log(storeList);
```

Will print each individual item.

Comment: Perfect. Is there a way to filter that data and then output that? So rather than having return result; I can have return storeList;

Comment: If you want the results of map filtered you can add an if statement inside your map function. For example : `if(storeList.storeName === "apple") {//do something}`

Comment: I'm actually using if ((store.StoreName.indexOf($scope.query) >=0) || $scope.query === undefined) {//doing something here} I have the data returning filtered here. I can see the output in the console using console.log(storeList). I'm wondering how I get return storeList outside the scope of this map() into the parent scope. At that point it will get called into my function.  When I move it outside the scope of that function, i see unresolved variable. I'm sure this is simple, but banging head right now...

Comment: Try creating an array outside your map function and push the filtered results into this new array.  Something like ```var newArray = [];   oldArray.map(function(item){ if("condition"){ newArray.push(item);} });```

Answer (score 0):

Using suggestions from @F.P I was able to create new array outside of original function where I performed .filter method and if statements to filter indexOf $scope.query and then .push that onto result. Works perfectly.